# Adding Framework to Swift Project

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use the [SwiftIconFont Framework](https://github.com/0x73/SwiftIconFont) in my project. I followed all the directions listed. I added `pod 'SwiftIconFont', '~> 2.7'` then performed `pod install`. The terminal spits out:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
...
...
Installing SwiftIconFont (2.7.0)
...
...
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 8 dependencies from the Podfile and 13 total pods installed.
```

Judging from this terminal message, `SwiftIconFont` should have been successfully installed on my project. However, when I go to my project to try to link the `SwiftIconFont` framework, the added directory appears to be empty.

[image: SwiftIconFont directory is empty]

I tried to `import SwiftIconFont` but Xcode says no such module exists. What else should I do to be able to use this framework?

I also added `github "0x73/SwiftIconFont"` to my Cartfile, then performed `carthage update`, even though this step may be unnecessary.

Comment: just restart your xcode and try again

Comment: Are you openning the .xcworkspace file ?

Comment: CocoaPods and Carthage use different approaches to handle dependencies in your projects, so you have to decide which one to use. For CocoaPods, make sure that you're using the `.xcworkspace` instead of the usual `.xcodeproj`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this happens, but one way to solve your issue is to go into your build settings and defining the Framework Search Paths to a folder which contains the frameworks in question. If the frameworks are placed in your project directory, simply set the framework search path to $(SRCROOT) and set it to recursive.